# Obj.SetInfo() error obj has no method SetInfo()

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm getting the error below using Windows PowerShell. Does anyone know how to correct it?

```
ERROR: Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject]
doesn't contain a method named 'SetInfo'.
No.psf (97, 25): ERROR: At Line: 97 char: 25

ERROR: + $computerObject.SetInfo <<<< ()
ERROR: + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SetInfo:String) [], RuntimeException
ERROR: + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

I am sorry for not posting the code. I am still having the issue of the error.

```psh
$No_Load = {
  # Load the ActiveDirectory module if it's available
  # Check if the ActiveDirectory module is installed
  if ((Get-Module -ListAvailable | where { $_.Name -eq 'ActiveDirectory' }) -eq $null) {
    $labelDialogRedNewNo.Text += "You need to install the ActiveDirectory module!`n"
  } else {
    # Check if the ActiveDirectory module is allready Imported
    if ((Get-Module ActiveDirectory) -eq $null) {
      Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
      $labelDialogGreenNewNo.Text += "ActiveDirectory module imported`n"
    } else {
      $labelDialogGreenNewNo.Text += "ActiveDirectory already imported`n"
    }
  }

  #Initialize variables
  $dateTime = Get-Date -Format G
  $computerName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property Name).Name
  $userName = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -Property UserName).UserName

  #These Varables for display
  $companyComputer = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*Computers*"' | select name -ExpandProperty name)
  $distinguishedName = (Get-ADComputer ($computerName) -Property DistinguishedName).DistinguishedName
  $computerObject = (Get-ADObject ($distinguishedName))
  $location = (Get-ADObject ($distinguishedName) -Properties Location).Location
  $departmentNumber = (Get-ADObject ($distinguishedName) -Properties DepartmentNumber).DepartmentNumber
  $company = (Get-ADObject ($distinguishedName) -Properties Company).Company
  $accountType = (Get-ADObject ($distinguishedName) -Properties ExtensionAttribute15).ExtensionAttribute15

  #Initialize Form Controls
  $txtBillingCodeNewNo.Text = $departmentNumber
  $lblComputerNameNewNo.Text = $computerName
  $lblUserNameNewNo.Text = $userName
  $lblPhysicalLocationNewNo.Text = $location
  $comboboxATNewNo.Text = $accountType

  $comboboxOUNewNo.Text = $company
  #$comboboxATNewNo.Text = $companyComputer
  Load-ComboBox -ComboBox $comboboxOUNewNo (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase 'OU=Agencies,DC=state,DC=in,DC=us' -Filter * -Properties Name | select name -ExpandProperty name)
  #Load-ComboBox -ComboBox $comboboxOUNewNo (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*Computers*"' | select name -ExpandProperty name)
}

#region Control Helper Functions
function Load-ComboBox {
  Param (
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox]$ComboBox,
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    $Items,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$DisplayMember,
    [switch]$Append
  )

  if (-not $Append) {
    $ComboBox.Items.Clear()
  }

  if ($Items -is [Object[]]) {
    $ComboBox.Items.AddRange($Items)
  } elseif ($Items -is [Array]) {
    $ComboBox.BeginUpdate()
    foreach ($obj in $Items) {
      $ComboBox.Items.Add($obj)
    }
    $ComboBox.EndUpdate()
  } else {
    $ComboBox.Items.Add($Items)
  }

  $ComboBox.DisplayMember = $DisplayMember
}

$btnSubmitNewNo_Click = {
  $computerObject.name = 'IOT'
  $computerObject.company = 'IOT'
  $computerObject.departmentNumber = $departmentNumber
  $computerObject.extensionAttribute15 = $accountType
  $computerObject.SetInfo() 
}
```

When I set a breakpoint I am getting all the relevant values, most importantly the `computerObject`. However when I attempt the `SetInfo()` I get the error. Can anyone help with this? Again all of the `computerObject.properties` have values but I get the error on the `SetInfo()` (line 97).

Comment: Sorry but my question is does anyone know how to correct this error

Comment: Show us the command(s) you're running

Comment: I've placed this into code tags as it makes the error message more legible. I tried the quote tag but it looked just as bad as before. I moved OP's comment up into the post: they are looking for any ideas as to what might fix this error.

Comment: It's going to be real hard to diagnose without more info, like the command that was on line 97 and the line preceding it.

Comment: @Irwin Fixing the error is simple: put an object into `$computerObject` that actually does have a method `SetInfo()`. As for finding out why that currently isn't happening: you'll have to show the code that sets the variable `$computerObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You retrieve the computer object via `Get-ADObject`:

```
$computerObject = (Get-ADObject ($distinguishedName))
```

This returns a `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject` object which doesn't have a `SetInfo()` method.

If you want to set attributes via `SetInfo()` retrieve the computer object via [ADSI](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx):

```
$computerObject = [adsi]"LDAP://$distinguishedName"
```

If you want to retrieve the computer object via `Get-ADObject` set the attributes via [`Set-ADObject`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617254.aspx):

```
Set-ADObject -Instance $computerObject
```

However, the best way, since you're dealing with computer objects, is probably to use [`Get-ADComputer`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx) and [`Set-ADComputer`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617263.aspx).